# generate dynamically an array of functions integrating a parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that takes an index as a parameter :

```js
function awesomeFunction(index) {
  console.log(index); // does awesome stuff depending on the index
}
```

Now, I would like to dynamically create an array of such functions, each one using NO PARAMETER AT ALL. Here is what I have in mind :

```js
function generateAwesomeFunction(index) {
  return function () {
    console.log(index);
  }
}

var awesomeArray = [];

for (var i=0 ; i<something ; i++) {
  awesomeArray.push(generateAwesomeFunction(i));  
}
```

In my twisted mind, the output `awesomeArray` should contain functions, none of these takes any parameter, but all of these do different things because the `index` is INTEGRATED in the function when generated. For instance, the following calls execute a different code :

```js
awesomeArray[0]();
awesomeArray[1]();
// and so on...
```

A running example is :

```js
function awesomeFunction(index) {
  console.log(index); // does awesome stuff depending on the index
}

function generateAwesomeFunction(index) {
  return function () {
    console.log(index);
  }
}

var awesomeArray = [];

for (var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) {
  awesomeArray.push(generateAwesomeFunction(i));  
}

awesomeArray[0](); // 0
awesomeArray[1](); // 1
awesomeArray[2](); // 2
// and so on...
```

Questions :

1. Does it work ? ---> YES !
2. Is there a BETTER way to generate that array of functions ?

Comment: *Does it work?* have you tried it?

Comment: @Matt Burland : just did, produced an undefined error, updated my question. Sorry.

Comment: `something is not defined` - okay, so that's your problem. What did you expect it to think `something` was? That's a variable, it needs to be defined somewhere and you didn't define it. If before your loop you put `var something = 5` then it would work.

Comment: Where did you define something?

Comment: oh gosh I'm stupid, wait a sec...

Comment: The code you posted does not contain `something`

Comment: @Matt Burland : seems like it works ! But is it a correct / efficient way to implement my idea ? gccampbell suggested `Function#bind`, but I feel like it's even more complicated...

Comment: @Bergi : <stupid joke> the code I posted DOES contain something, how rude of you ! </stupid joke>

Comment: @KLôN: It would've been even better if the variable was named `anything` :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bind` and partial application to create a new function from `awesomeFunction` that will always be invoked with a specific `index` parameter. In this case, it doesn't matter what value of `this` you foward to the function.

You don't need the `generateAwesomeFunction` function.

```js
function awesomeFunction(index) {
  console.log(index); // does awesome stuff depending on the index
}
var awesomeArray = [];

for (var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) {
  awesomeArray.push(awesomeFunction.bind(this, i));  
}

awesomeArray[0](); // 0
awesomeArray[1](); // 1
awesomeArray[2](); // 2
```

Comment: ah, I was just completing your answer to get rid of the function generator, but you did it too ! Thanks, perfect answer to improve my code !